# Is there a kdevelop version that i can install on windows?

Tags: windows, kdevelop, kdevelop4

is there any other than using Cygwin? thanks!

Comment: As said in my other comment, KDevelop is now readily available on Windows: https://www.kdevelop.org/download

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KDE 4 supports Windows, and you can check the install methods from [this](http://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Build/KDE4/Windows) and [here](http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/KDE_on_Windows/Installation#KDE_Installer_for_Windows).

Note that you will have to use either MinGW or MSVC as the compiler, though.

Comment: i installed the kde4, but how do i install my kdeveloper? thanks.

Comment: @craftace: I only found this: http://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Build/KDE4/Windows/GCC_And_MinGW which seem to suggest build it from source. I normally don't use Windows, so I only know the news that KDE4 supports Windows, but never tried. However, because the official KDE4 has released for more than a year, I hope and believe you'll be able to install it.

Comment: i installed the kde4 but where is the kdeveloper software? sorry im quite lost now

Answer (score 21):

I've installed kdevelop on win7, using emerge:  http://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Build/Windows/emerge.

To get it all working is a pain in the ass, mostly because there is no guide.

---

Here is how I did it:

- Install python and git.
- Create a directory where you want to install kde. Name it kde4, i.e. `C:\kde4`. This is futher called `%KDEROOT%`.
- Go to `%KDEROOT%`, using `cd %KDEROOT%`.
- Run

  ```
  git clone git://anongit.kde.org/emerge.git
  ```

  in this directory.
- Make directory `%KDEROOT%\etc`.
- Copy from 
  `%KDEROOT%\emerge\kdesettings-example.bat` to `%KDEROOT%\etc\kdesettings.bat`, and change settings as preferred.
- Run:

  ```
  cd emerge && git checkout kde-4.7
  ```

  then go to `%KDEROOT%\emerge` and run `kdeenv.bat`.

  This will open a new window.
  Here you can start the building of kde.
- Run `emerge qt`, `emerge kdelibs`, `emerge kde-baseapps`, `emerge kdevelop` and `emerge kdevelop-pg-qt`.

  This will take a while.
- Now you need to make two bat files in the `%KDEROOT%\bin` directory.

  The first should be called `kbuildsycoca4.bat` and contain:

  ```
  @ECHO OFF

  ECHO Initialize KDE environment
  SET KDEROOT=%~dsp0\..
  SET KDEBIN=%KDEROOT%\bin
  SET KDELIB=%KDEROOT%\lib
  SET KDELIB_KDE4=%KDELIB%\kde4
  SET KDESHARE=%KDEROOT%\share
  SET KDESHARE_KDE4=%KDESHARE%\kde4
  SET KDEDEV_UTILS=%KDEROOT%\dev-utils
  SET GIT_LOC=%KDEDEV_UTILS%\git\bin
  SET SVN_LOC=%KDEDEV_UTILS%\svn\bin
  SET PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\Public\Programs\Python27\App <-- This is only nessecary if     it is not in your environment

  SET PATH=%PATH%;%GIT_LOC%;%SVN_LOC%
  SET KDEDIRS=%KDEROOT%;%KDEBIN%;%KDELIB%;%KDESHARE%;%KDEDEV_UTILS%;%KDELIB_KDE4%;%KDESHARE_KDE4%
  SET kbuildsycoca4_binary=%KDEBIN%\kbuildsycoca4.exe

  ECHO Running kbuildsycoca4
  :run
  CALL  "%kbuildsycoca4_binary%"
  CALL  "%kbuildsycoca4_binary%" --noincremental
  CALL  "%kbuildsycoca4_binary%" --checkstamps
  pause
  ```

  and the second one should be called `kdevelop.bat` and contain:

  ```
  @ECHO OFF

  ECHO Initialize KDE environment
  SET KDEROOT=%~dsp0\..
  SET KDEBIN=%KDEROOT%\bin
  SET KDELIB=%KDEROOT%\lib
  SET KDELIB_KDE4=%KDELIB%\kde4
  SET KDESHARE=%KDEROOT%\share
  SET KDESHARE_KDE4=%KDESHARE%\kde4
  SET KDEDEV_UTILS=%KDEROOT%\dev-utils
  SET GIT_LOC=%KDEDEV_UTILS%\git\bin
  SET SVN_LOC=%KDEDEV_UTILS%\svn\bin
  SET PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\Public\Programs\Python27\App <-- This is only nessecary if it is not in your environment

  SET PATH=%PATH%;%GIT_LOC%;%SVN_LOC%
  SET KDEDIRS=%KDEROOT%;%KDEBIN%;%KDELIB%;%KDESHARE%;%KDEDEV_UTILS%;%KDELIB_KDE4%;%    KDESHARE_KDE4%
  SET kdev_binary=%KDEBIN%\kdevelop.exe

  ECHO Starting kdevelop
  :run
  CALL  "%kdev_binary%"
  ```

Now it should run.

I still have trouble with the kDevCmakeManager plugin and the source formatter settings under settings->kdevelop settings->source formatter. It crashes then.

Answer (score 7):

KDevelop core developer here.

KDevelop 5 is now available for Windows, head over to:
  https://www.kdevelop.org/download