# How can i run the command emerge in git?

Tags: c, git, qt, kdevelop

this is my 1st question here!
On this site: [Is there a kdevelop version that i can install on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101595/is-there-a-kdevelop-version-that-i-can-install-on-windows/8740657#8740657?newreg=fcfd0cf5e5de46cf814bbd1e3db6a4ac) at one of the answers it is required to "Run emerge qt, emerge kdelibs, emerge kde-baseapps, emerge kdevelop and emerge kdevelop-pg-qt". However, when i make this it tells in the cmd.exe: "The command 'emerge' is either misspelled or could not be found." How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `emerge` actually installable on Windows if you follow the guide on the https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Build_from_source/Windows#Installing_Emerge

For info:

`emerge` is a command of a Portage package manager (program to install software in the OS).

Portage is an official package manager of the Gentoo Linux OS. Other examples: Ubuntu and Debian Linux use Apt package manager, Fedora Linux uses fpm, ArchLinux uses pacman, etc...

Comment: Be that as it may, `emerge` [is the official way](https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Build_from_source/Windows) to build KDE from source on Windows.

Comment: Not really, no. I have never done it, only heard about it. Thank you for editing your answer, though.